# Kubernetes pod fail to connect to timescaledb in first few tries

Tags: python, postgresql, kubernetes, timescaledb

I am trying to run these things:

1. Similar multiple pods (10 in total) to get FX rates from an exchange. Each pod will pull a specific FX rate every 10 seconds at the same time and save to a DB pod.
2. Save the FX rates in each pod to a timescaledb pod with PVC. From what I understand, timescaledb runs on postgresql. So my `timescaledb.yaml` file uses postgres env. However, I am getting this error in the first few tries for some of the pods when deploying all 10 pods at the same time:
   `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "timescaledb-service" (10.43.179.113) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`.

On average, it runs ok after 3 - 5 tries for some of the pods.

3. I am also running cronjobs for each of the FX rates (10 of them) to pull out rates daily at midnight for a downstream process. I am getting the same error as above too when trying to pull out the rates for most of the cronjobs pods. For now, I am using `restartPolicy: OnFailure` with `backoffLimit: 20` to make sure the cronjobs run successfully. Similar to above, on average, it runs ok after 3 - 5 tries for some of the pods, with a max retry of 8.

I am using sqlalchemy to connect to timescaledb.

Wondering how do I fix the connection refused issue. I have been searching on stackoverflow for similar questions/answers, but have yet to find them.

I appreciate any help on this!

pv_claim.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-claim
  namespace: get-rates
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 40Gi
```

timescaledb.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: timescaledb
  namespace: get-rates
  labels:
    app: get-rates
    namespace: get-rates
    group: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: get-rates
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: get-rates
        group: api
    spec:
      hostname: get-rates-timescaledb-service
      containers:
      - name: timescaledb
        image: timescale/timescaledb:2.1.1-pg13
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: get-rates-secret
              key: timescaledb-root-username
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: get-rates-secret
              key: timescaledb-root-password
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: get-rates-secret
              key: timescaledb-default-db
        volumeMounts:
            - name: pv-claim
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: pv-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pv-claim
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: get-rates-timescaledb-service
  namespace: get-rates
  labels:
    group: api
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: get-rates
  ports:
    - name: get-rates-service
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

get-price.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: price-puller-eur-usd
  namespace: get-rates
  labels:
    app: get-rates
    namespace: get-rates
    group: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: get-rates
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: get-rates
        group: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: price-puller
        image: <price-puller-image>
        ports: 
          - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: get-rates-secret
              key: timescaledb-root-username
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: get-rates-secret
              key: timescaledb-root-password
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: get-rates-secret
              key: timescaledb-default-db
        - name: POSTGRES_HOST
          value: get-rates-timescaledb-service.get-rates.svc.cluster.local
        - name: SYMBOL
          value: 'EUR/USD'
        - name: POSTGRES_PORT
          value: '5432'
```

Comment: Is the timescales running all the time?

Comment: yup timescaledb and the 10 pods in part 1 are running all the time

Comment: So, if the timescaledb is up and running and the other pods starts afterwads, they should actually get their connection immediately and without any issues. That's a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your service selector is:

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: get-rates
```

Your db pod labels:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: timescaledb
  namespace: get-rates
[...]
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: get-rates
        group: api
```

and price-puller labels:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: price-puller-eur-usd
[...]
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: get-rates
        group: api
```

They all have the same labels.

Your service `get-rates-timescaledb-service` is forwarding requestst not only to a timescale DB, but also to every other pod that matches the selector, and that means that by random it will choose the price-puller-eur-usd pod and forward the request to it, but since there is no db running, you will get connection refused.

Run the following command:

```
kubectl get endpoints
```

it will show you all the endpoints for sepcific service. Make sure it lists only the pods you want and don't reuse the labels.

Read more about [services in k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)